# Redis-Cluster Cache for PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, redis, spring-data-redis

I have configured JPA Repository with method getUsers which will return all users as a List from PostgreSQL DB. I have also configured Redis cache at my local. When I invoke calls to getUsers multiple times, data is fetched from Local cache. DB call is not happening as expected. But when values are fetched from cache, User Model has a field ID which is type of UUID, that is coming as NULL. How to configure getUsers method to populate user details with UUID from Redis Cache.  `@Cacheable("users")`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by implementing Serializable for my model base class which is having ID field.